# How to config hound-ci to support python2.7

Tags: python, styles

Hound ci uses flake8, and flake8 depends on python running env, it looks like hound ci is using python3 as env, does any know how to config hound ci to work with python2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure HoundCI to check code written on python 2.x at this moment. Hound support only python3.x in a proper way.
If you trying to check the code you probably got "wrong" hound's messages for python2 like:

```
print "hello"
# should be flagged as a Syntax Error
```

or in other cases like a missed builtins namespace in Python 3 which you may use for version 2.x like

```
for _ in xrange(n)]
# should be flagged as undefined name 'xrange'
```

So, in this cases, you can hack HundCI. To configure Hound to ignore this errors put configuration file for flake8 `.flake8.ini` in your project root:

```
[flake8]
ignore =
    # E999 SyntaxError
    E999,
    # undefined name
    F821

 # But in 'undefined name' case would be better to specify builtins
 builtins = 'xrange'
```

Here is a [list](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/error-codes.html) of Errors / Violations

Then, tell Hound to use linter config with specified ignores. Add path to flake8 config to your `.hound.yml`:

```
python:
  enabled: true
  config_file: .flake8.ini
```

Comment: Thx，that‘s really helpful